# Rigify issue - poorly distributed weights

Tags: animation, rigging, weight-painting, rigify

Ive used rigify once before, to rig a bird. I had some issues which were fixed by scaling the mesh up by a factor of 10. Now I'm rigging a human. I've tried scaling up the mesh, to get a good weight map and solve general rigify issues, but it's not working this time.

Once I bind the mesh, it's very poorly done - raising the arm affects polygons in the legs. Left leg polys also affect the right leg etc.

Can anyone help me get a good weight map without having to do manual weight painting /envelopes?

*EDIT* UPDATED file here:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Your mesh has no vertex groups. Did you know this when sending the file?

Comment: I didn't know that this would have an effect on rigify. Sorry if that's basic - I'm a C4D user coming to blender to use the animation tools. Are vertex groups necessary for rigify?

Comment: The normals on your mesh are inverted. They point to the inside of the mesh instead of the outside. You don't want this, as a rule. Shift + n while in Edit Mode to reverse them.

Comment: The reason I mention the missing vertex groups is because you tell a story in the OP about the trouble you're having with your vertex weights. So I expected to get a file that shows the problem with your vertex weights. But you have no vertex groups, and you can't have vertex weights without vertex groups. So what I'm wondering is, why do I have a file with no vertex groups, and how do I investigate that file to find out what's wrong with your vertex weights?

Comment: You also only have the metarig. And no armature modifier. It looks as if no rig generation, and no skinning, ever took place in this file. Is that true? Why have you sent a file that has none of the work done that you mention having trouble with in the OP?

Comment: ah I see what you mean - I removed the bad rigging in the file because it wasn't working, and uploaded that one instead. If you look at the question, I've now replaced the file with one that has automatically generated weights. Thanks for pointing out the inverted normals thing as well - not sure how that happened as my source FBX was fine

Comment: Why did you initially upload "that one instead"?

Comment: Solved - think it was the normals - thanks for the help! :)